# Show Subcategories ON Same Categories In Images Page Laravel

Tags: laravel

want to show subcategories from the same categories on the Images  page

Subcategory Database- https://prnt.sc/26cr0jl Images Database - https://prnt.sc/26cr0t8

Demo -https://cbeditz.com/photo/15384/yellow-cb-editing-background-full-hd-download

`@foreach( App\Models\SubCategories::where('categories_id', '=', 'images->categories_id')->get() as $subcategories )`

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have relationship setup between `Category` and `SubCategory` Models
You should pass these variables from a controller.

In your controller where you are loading view and you have `category id` coming from a route request.

```
$sub_categories = Category::with('sub_categories')->find($category_id);

return view('your-view', compact('sub_categories'));
```

And in your view you can use it like

```
@foreach($sub_categories as $sub_category)
   {{ $sub_category->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i want to show   subcategories from same categories  on the images page see this link-https://cbeditz.com/photo/15383/white-scorpio-cb-editing-background-full-hd-download